# Installing Microsoft Teams in Powershell using a MSI file already downloaded on your computer

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, microsoft-teams

So I have been looking for a day or so now on a way to get microsoft teams installed on workstations. This is my code that I have used to write scripts for many other MSI's and Exe's. I got this file from microsofts documentation for installing teams

$file = C:\Teams_windows_x64.msi

$Arguments = @(
"/i"
(' "{0}" ' -f $file.fullname)
"/quiet"
"/norestart"
'OPTIONS="noAutoStart=true" '
"ALLUSERS=1"
)

Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $Arguments -Wait -NoNewWindow

when i do this for just about any other MSI or EXE ill get it to work. However, I have not been able to get this to work at all. All it does is await more input after I press enter. I do know that there is a microsoft teams module but id prefer not to use that. I know that this may be a weird way of having a collection of arguments but this is how ive always done it. Thank you

Edit: thought I should mention that the reason why im trying to install it with a file already on the computer is because i use DattoRMM and they have a way for you to upload the file you wanna use and then reference it in the script. but im trying to get it to work on my local computer first.

Comment: This is a little over complicated to just run the msi. `msiexec /I "C:\Teams_windows_x64.msi" /quiet /no restart` should be all you really need.

Comment: Wouldn’t that be how you write it in command prompt?

Comment: Where do you download this MSI? You can try something like: `msiexec.exe /i Teams_windows_x64.msi ALLUSERS=1 OPTIONS="noAutoStart=true" /qn /norestart` I have seen elsewhere.

Comment: It looks like this MSI just installs another installer under program files and then exits ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/msi-deployment#pc-installation)). It then registers that EXE installer to run on login or Windows boot. It looks pretty clunky.

Comment: Msiexec is a .exe utility, not a cmd/cmdlet. This mean that msiexec has its own syntax on how to run stuff. What you're doing is "powershells" way of supplying it arguments.

Comment: Stein my boss wants it done in powershell

Comment: Abraham, oh ok i see. so then how come its worked for every other MSI that ive tried to install besides this one?

Comment: You need to run the executable that is installed with the MSI and put under program files, or you can install it like that and then reboot the computer and log in as another user. See if that does it. Finally you can use the exe installer outright (without any MSI) to install for each user. That might be possible to do with AD - if you have that set up.

Comment: so i decided to try it in command prompt just to see if it would work and im getting the same error that i got when i first ran it in datto "the installation package could not be opened."

Comment: i originally was working with the .exe but then i found out that for it to actually install you have to be logged on as the current user for it to install

Comment: Can you add it to a logon script? Or push a shortcut to the desktop for people to invoke the installation themselves? Do you have Active Directory set up? How many machines are we talking about?

Comment: I don't have access to AD / Group Policy deployment, but [here is a video on AD / GPO deployment for exe files](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYGMsu5KCPQ). See 1 minute in for a list of deployment types and the workaround for exe files. Prefer one of the package types supported natively.

Comment: @MrClayGiovanni Any update on this?

Comment: We came to the conclusion that for this particular software we couldn’t install it this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the Answer for better knowledge
Copying from @MrClayGiovanni comments

For this particular software we couldn’t install it this way